# ASP.NET publishing creating not all database

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I have a little problem with publishing my application.
Here's the DbContext:

```
public class UsersDb : DbContext
{
    public DbSet<Users> Users { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Locations> Locations { get; set; }
}
```

When i'm publishing my application, all tables (Users and __MigrationHistory) are creating on SQL server database, but Locations table isn't.

I'm trying to use Package/Publish SQL tab in project properties, but got and error

*Error MSB4018: The "SqlScriptPreprocessSqlVariables" task failed unexpectedly*

Also tried to use several DbContexts but with no luck. Locations table was still not created.

Comment: Check if bin folder contains `EntityFramework.SqlServer.dll`

Comment: Checked. Dll is in the folder.

Comment: Might be related to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36721750/visual-studio-2015-exception-sqlscriptpreprocesssqlvariables-when-running-web-pu